# A query to get list of records whose ids exist in another table but with a different value for other column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables that have the same structure(one for 2012 and one for 2013), both with details of people and their job id. I am looking to find the list of all the people who got a promotion. I know that a person got the promotion only if their person id existed in the 2012 table but the position id has been changed. I know I can use exists and get all the records that are in 2012 table, but how do I check for the fact that the records in two tables should have different values for position ids?

Table 1 & 2:

pers_id, name, dept,salary, job id.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2012 t1
INNER JOIN table2013 t2 ON t1.tableID = t2.tableID
WHERE t1.position <> t2.position;
```

`tableId` is the identifier for each record in your table. I'm not sure if that is pers_id or you have a different id.

Comment: Access throws a syntax error with `!=`, so change the `WHERE` condition to `t1.position <> t2.position`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Data2013.pers_id
FROM Data2013 INNER JOIN Data2012
  ON (Data2013.pers_id = Data2012.pers_id) AND (Data2013.position_id <> Data2012.position_id);
```